# Pytorch already installed using Conda but fails when called

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conda

I am trying to install `pytorch` for using BERT but when following the installation instructions found here: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/ I am getting an error.

When I try and initalise the BERT model I get the following error:

```
ImportError: 
    BertForSequenceClassification requires the PyTorch library but it was not found in your environment. 
    Checkout the instructions on theinstallation page: https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/
    and follow the ones that match your environment.
```

I have followed the instructions and run the following command line in my Conda prompt terminal AND in my current working directory:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

It looks to complete but when I try and call the following line I get the same error as the start as if it hasn't installed at all.

Can anyone help me out please.

EDIT:

The code I am using to execute bert is:

```
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(r'C:\Users\441\bert\pytorch_model.bin', config = r'C:\Users\441\bert\config.json')
```

Comment: What code are you executing?

Comment: @Ivan I have added an edit

Comment: Could you make sure PyTorch is installed in your environment? Use `conda list | grep torch`

Comment: I get 'grep' is not recognized as an internal or external command` when trying to run that line from the command line or jupyter notebook.

Comment: Just do `conda list` then, and look for `torch`

Comment: torch                     1.7.1
torchaudio                0.7.2 
torchvision               0.8.2

Comment: @Ivan They seem to be there

Comment: @Ivan FYI, `conda list` accepts a positional regex argument, so no need for `grep`. Simply `conda list torch` works, and doesn't drop the header information.

Comment: How are you running the code? Are you sure the Python session you run is the Conda environment where you installed PyTorch?

Comment: @merv I'm running my code within a Jupyter Notebook which I have initialised from the Anaconda Navigator. If I checked `conda list` in my notebook and it's there, I take it that means that it is in my current environment or is there another possibility? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue (same error msg), and after using conda list | grep torch I also found it is there. What worked for me is that I restarted the jupyter notebook kernel and the error is gone.